Do all linear transformations need to have equal columns and rows in order to be onto?
I remember learning in class that if your linear transformation is going from  $\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R^m}$, then the transformation matrix T must have N columns and M rows. We also learned the two conditions for a linear transformation to be onto are:
a)If A ∼ B and B is in echelon form, then T is onto if and only if B has a pivot position in every row.
b) If n > m, then T is not onto.
Does this mean that all onto transformations must be have equal numbers of columns and rows (and therefore going from $\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow  \mathbb{R^n}$)? I can't think of a way that a matrix could have a pivot position in every row and also have more rows than columns. Am I misunderstanding what it means for something to be onto?

Your exponents $\Bbb N,\Bbb M$ look strange. For surjectivity, we do not need $m=n$. Think of the map from $\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R$, $(a,b)\mapsto a+b$.

It seems you are misunderstanding the echelon form and what a pivot element is, rather. You should have no problem coming up with an onto map for $m = 1$ and $n \geq 1$, say.

The statement b) is quite incorrect.
